# Change who is logged in upon boot

Tags: boot, raspberry-pi, user

I just booted my Raspberry Pi, and created a new user, `nacht`.

Currently upon boot, I get a prompt logged in as `pi` but I want to be logged in as `nacht`. How do I change this setting?

Or should I simply rename the `pi` user?

My OS is Raspian.

Comment: Renaming 'pi' should be fine if you don't have any better idea.

Comment: Yeah I may do that... would still like an answer to my question about booting though...

Comment: perhaps it simply boots to whoever has uid=1000?

Comment: Please post the output of `sudo grep '/bin/login' /etc/inittab` (if it outputs anything)

Comment: I've actually fixed this via `raspi-config` but would still like to know how to do it on a regular linux machine. `sudo grep '/bin/login' /etc/inittab` gives nothing, but as i've said, i've fixed this now. it appears my machine uses getty instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

open up the file:

```
sudo vim /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Change the following line to your username:

```
autologin-user=pi
```

Comment: What about for console autologin? (lightdm is only for GUI, right?)